# How do I invoke CSS in a different folder?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Želim započeti izradu web stranice
How to separate html, css, javascript into 2 different folders.
One folder will contain a file that will only write HTML and JavaScript,and the second folder will have a file that will only write css.
How do I invoke CSS in the first folder?

Comment: `<link rel=“stylesheet” href=“/folderNameGoesHere/style.css” />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that you have to use relative url (relative to the file the link is in). If the file is located in another folder in the same directory the file is in just prepend two dots and a slash `../` before the folder like the following:

`<link rel=“stylesheet” href=“../folderNameGoesHere/style.css” />`